# FileDialog in QTQuick (QML): Save file under given name

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2, qfiledialog

We're building a Qt Quick app, that must be able to save a file **under a given name**.

In the [FileDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickdialogs/qml-qtquick-dialogs1-filedialog.html) component you can only set a directory. This is not very user-friendly, since you don't want to type in a filename by hand every time you download a file.

So far we tried different things

1. FileDialog from QtQuick.Dialogs: filename cannot be set
2. Native dialog via QPlatformFileDialogHelper (naughty private c++ hack): filename cannot be set on Linux (Gnome)
3. Native dialog via static QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(): in Quick application there is no QWidget available for 'parent'
4. QT dialog via QFileDialog instance: Modality doeas not work, since 'parent' is not set. In Quick application there is no QWidget available for setParent() call

(Using C++ with QT 5.1 and QtQuick 2.1 incl. all desktop components)

Comment: IMO, the best way is the `QFileDialog` option with the parent set to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>This blog post covers the whole problem and provides a possible solution:
[Advanced FileDialog in QML (Save file under given name)](http://kullo.net/blog/advanced-filedialog-in-qml/)</s> (RIP Kullo blog)

The repository implementing the solution is here: https://github.com/kullo/qml-file-dialog-demo

Comment: He used private QT headers, which breaks when upgrading QT

Comment: Might breakt, jap. But I don't have any other chance. I'll try to keep it up-to-date since we're using it in our software.

Comment: In this post widgets module is used so I cannot get why he didn't create a wrapper above QFileDialog which has selectFile method?

Comment: @VALOD9 I tried hard to do that. But I did not have a QWidget available that I could use as a parent. Without a parent, modality does not work.

Comment: @SimonWarta I've just added a project sample to GitHub which demonstrates this possibility. And this project doesn't use private headers. Tested on Windows and Linux.

Comment: @VALOD9 okay, where? I'd like to have a look at it. Feel free to add it as an alternative answer here.

Comment: @SimonWarta sorry. I forgot to add a link :)

Comment: @SimonWarta link is posted as an answer.

Comment: Since the link is dead, [here is link](https://github.com/kullo/qml-file-dialog-demo) to original repository with implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I hope this will be still helpful. I found a compromise that at least works for me.
I used Qt.labs.platform 1.1 FileDialog QML Type: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-filedialog.html

```
FileDialog {
            id: saveDialog
            property MyClass myObj
            title: "Save Dialog"
            folder: myObjHasAPath? myObj.path: "file:///" //Here you can set your default folder
            currentFile: "file:///"+myObj.name //The name of the item that you want to save
            fileMode: Platform.FileDialog.SaveFile
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the FileDialog selectExisting property to false.

Comment: `selectExisting` is not a valid property name