# How to set QFileDialog's parent to a QQuickView

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2, qfiledialog

The only window in my application is a `QQuickView` which is a subclass of `QWindow`, not of `QWidget`, so if I want to use a `QFileDialog` to give the user the option to save a file, I do not know how to set its parent to be the `QQuickView`. I know that the `QFileDialog` works without a parent, but if it does not have a parent, it is not centered over the `QQuickView`. This is not a big problem on its own, but on my OS (Ubuntu 13.10) a `QFileDialog` without a parent sometimes appears under the `QQuickView` window and the user sees only a “flashing” taskbar icon.

I use Qt 5.2. I initially tried to use the `FileDialog` type in the Qt Quick Dialogs module but it does not have some features I need (such as the `defaultSuffix` property).

Answer (score 0):

Right, this is a serious problem of QML. You cannot utilize the `QFileDialog` because you don't have a QWidget app and `FileDialog` lacks some critical features.

See: [FileDialog in QTQuick (QML): Save file under given name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302838/filedialog-in-qtquick-qml-save-file-under-given-name)

At the moment we are using code from deep down in the Qt source code, which is not in the public API. It only requires a Window instead of a Widget to do modality right.

Maybe I can write a blog post about that over Christmas.