# SaveAs feature Qt5.3+ QML FileDialog?

Tags: qml, filedialog

Is there a functional cross-platform SaveAs feature in the Qt5.3+ QML FileDialog?

If not, is there a best practice for providing a similar feature?

FileDialog can be used for Save As in Desktop, but the initial filename can't be set. Also in Android there is no place in the dialog to add a file name.

I've tried the workaround "hack" regarding this subject posted elsewhere. It doesn't help.

Comment: please provide links to the workaround, and relevant things you have tried.

Comment: The hack is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302838/filedialog-in-qtquick-qml-save-file-under-given-name ... I'll prepare a simple example of "other things" in a day or so.